# HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies error while publishing my MVC .net 3.1 core project to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Not sure what details I should be providing to be completely honest, other than I googled and searched for this solution and I deleted everything and retried and didnt work out, I downloaded all the files needed, I added application settings and it added an error for me telling me that I need to install or update Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App, version 3.1.0, which I have installed and already existed anyway

I tried going to application event logs on Azure portal, there was 3 errors[image] first this one which some people suggested going to web.config and changing it to Module not v2, and I dont see any web.config file in my mvc project

2nd error [image] which I already talked about but its just not working, so I assume somehow its not seeing it??

3rd error [image] Also this I am not quite sure what to do with it.

Lastly, as I said I am not sure what information I should provide, I dont have much time and I was asked to publish it on azure there was no problems and seemed easy but errors popped up and nothing on the internet fixed my issues, you can comment and I will add any required data to fix this.
Thanks in advance

I installed each and every package in the dotnet folder to make sure everything is right and everytime it recognized there is a file already and asked me if I want to repair I said yes but that didnt help

I checked my .json file if it had any errors like some people suggested

checked if Azure portal specified that I am using ASP.NET 3.1core which it did

~~I used search for "stdoutLogFile" to check if I can find it anywhere on my solution since I cant find my web.config but I there was no result~~
I found out that I can add the web.config and make changes to it, and I did so but there was no result for it, still same error (yes I change the publish profile and republish to make sure it took the changes)

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgiVi.png I got these errors when I opened the profile.arm.json folder under the server dependency folder

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247978/discussion-on-question-by-zaid-haddadin-http-error-500-31-ancm-failed-to-find).

Comment: From the error msgs, we can't help you more. Because we can't reproduce the issue, if you can tell us the steps how to reproduce the issue or create a sample project without any sensitive info, we can test in our side.

Comment: @JasonPan Yeah I am sorry I couldnt reply earlier or update on the issue 
I just had to change the deployment mode to Self-contained
Not sure why or how this fixed it but that what made it work at the end